# Multiline names spoil the badge sidebar style / Длинные имена участников портят стиль отображения значков на боковой панели

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, дизайн

On the [badges help page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), in the sidebar, there is a bug.

When someone has a multi line name, the name goes onto two lines and splits up the nice line of badges. I suggest that names end with a "..." (or whatever is used in russian) to make it look cleaner.

<kbd>[image: введите описание изображения здесь]</kbd><kbd>[image: введите описание изображения здесь]</kbd>

---

На странице [Справка / Знаки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) в боковой панели есть ошибка.

Длинные имена участников не вмещаются на одну строчку и разбивают стройный столбец названий значков. Я предлагаю не переносить длинные имена на новую строку, а использовать "..." (или еще что-то, что принято использовать в России), чтобы боковая панель выглядела однородной.

UPD: 2016 год, пока не исправлено.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Можно применить к ссылкам решение из второй части [этого ответа](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433516/178988).